# Connection time in Delhi, separate tickets

Tags: short-connections, connecting-flights, del, virgin-atlantic, spicejet

We are considering a connection in Delhi (DEL). Coming in on Virgin Atlantic (from LHR), continuing on Spicejet to BKK on separate tickets. As far as I can tell both airlines operate out of Terminal 3. I assume we can't connect airside and will need to go through immigration & customs to check in with SpiceJet. We'll need (and can get) proper visa for this.

How much minimum time should be budget? Typically I would budget 4 hours for something like this (2 hours actual transfer time plus 2 hours of margin for delays etc) However, I've never been to India or Delhi, so I would like to get an opinion from travelers that have been there whether this is in the right ballpark.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Virgin 302, Google Flights notes that this LHR > DEL flight is "Often delayed 30+ minutes."  Because you have two separate tickets, if the first flight is late and/or immigration and customs slow and you aren't on time to check-in for the second flight, you'll be on your own to find and pay for a new ticket to Bangkok.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: I know that. That's why I'm budgeting a few hours of margin. 1 hour to get through immigration and customs, 20 minutes to get to the check in counter and drop bags. 30 minutes to go through security and to the gate. +2 hours for delays, lost bags, take a wrong turn, etc. The question here is: are these reasonable assumptions for Delhi airport. These reasonable assumptions for most airports I know, but I haven't been to Delhi and looking for some first hand experience